# Writing a text editor for a custom language

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am thinking of writing a plugin for VS 2010 that is just a text editor, so should automatically inherit the basic capabilities of a VS editor for example things like Bookmarking a line of code, adding TODOs, etc...BUT the keywords of my Custom language are different.
So I wanted to know what is the starting point to create such a thing? Is there some sort of editor that I can use and then it has some place to define my keywords for it? Some general ideas and starting point tips are appreciated.

Comment: oh! something more specific that pointing me to VS SDK tho :)

Comment: Visual Studio is very very very slow to load, etc. Do not expect it to be a replacement of notepad or tools like notepad++

Comment: @SteveB  yeah but I like those capabilities like AutoCompletion of the variable name or method names, etc that I define in that custom language...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at SharpDevelop (open source IDE in .net with some pretty nifty features): http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

If you want to stick with VS 2010 then this artical would probably be a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685514